# Issue with exporting information from predict function - date specifically in R

Tags: r, regression, predict

When I use the function below:

```
lapply(reg_results, function(model) {predict(model,newdata=subset(df, date=="12/15/2016 12:00:00 AM" & key=="1"))})
```

I get an output of regression results for a specific date based on x variables contained in df.

However, my df has several days for `key==1`. I want to export the regression results based on all dates, and print to say "df_results". My issue is, when I do the following:

```
lapply(reg_results, function(model) {predict(model,newdata=subset(DataNP, scenario_ID=="1", id=date))})
```

It outputs all the predictors for all dates, but the dates are showing as random numbers. They don't even appear to be numerically stored. Is there a way to bring in the column dates for each prediction output?

Example data set:

```
   Key  Date                     y   x1   x2   x3
   1    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   3    2    5
   1    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   5    7    2
   1    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    5   7    4    7 
   1    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   2    7    6
   2    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   6    3    8
   2    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   7    7    3
   2    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   2    3    4
   2    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   6    2    7
```

Essentially, I would like my regression predict function to show both the key and date next to each predict output so I can tie back to the insample data to compare.

Comment: The format for your "date" variable (mm/dd/yyyy) shows that you are not actually using R Dates. You are also not making it clear what it means to say "regression results based on all dates". You want a separate regression prediction for each date? If so the combination of these two issues means you probably have the "date" variable coded as a factor and your results are possibly a mess.

Comment: Please set up a reproducible example (i.e., something we can run that reproduces your issues) including data sample of *df*.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the OP with the sample data set

Comment: It appears I can do the following:

`as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")` but not sure how to implement that to correct the format within the df